# Kotlin - Configure Jackson to throw an exception when a field does not match with a certain value

Tags: kotlin, objectmapper

I have a service that receives a JSON with the following content:

```
{ 
  "name": "test", 
  "gender": "NOT_VALID"
}
```

that JSON should be mapped to this object "Person"

```
data class Person(var name: String, var gender: Gender)
```

Person has a name (String) and Gender is an enum like:

```
enum class Gender() {
    Male,
    Female,
    NotExplicit
}
```

I'm trying to implement a mapper that fails when the given Gender cant match with the explicit values that belongs to the enum.
For example, if I try to do something like these:

```
ObjectMapper.personValidate(text: String): Person =
try {
    
    val mapper = ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    val readValue: Person = mapper.readValue(text, Person::class.java)
    val person: Person = mapper.readValue(ByteArrayInputStream(text.toByteArray()), Person::class.java)
    person
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    when (e) {
      is JsonParseException, is JsonMappingException -> {
        throw PersonException()
      }
      else -> throw e
    }
  }
```

I'd expect an exception instead of the Person object.

This code right now is mapping gender to null when the value doesn't match.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. An exception will be thrown if you try to deserialize such a JSON into your `Person` class, simply because Jackson will not be able to deserialize the String `NOT_VALID` to a valid `Gender` value.

Comment: That's not ok, Jackson is ignoring the invalid value and translating it to null. I tried that before

Comment: That might be because of `ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)`. Have you tried without this?

Comment: yeap, but that's for something else the doc says: Feature that determines whether encountering unknown properties (ones that do not map to a property, and there is no "any setter" or handler that can handle it) should result in a failure (by throwing a JsonMappingException) or not. I tried it but doesn't work either

Comment: That is not the exact same thing as an invalid Enum value. You should be getting an exception.